# Recorrer JSON JavaScript NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Buenas,

Modifico la pregunta.

Como puedo recorrer en NODEJS JavaScript este JSON:

```
{
  "subscriptionId" : "5a268a598dc68904bbc7b3cf",
  "originator" : "localhost",
  "contextResponses" : [
    {
      "contextElement" : {
        "type" : "Temperatura",
        "isPattern" : "false",
        "id" : "S_Temp001",
        "attributes" : [
          {
            "name" : "Tem_int",
            "type" : "float",
            "value" : 2,
            "metadatas" : [
              {
                "name" : "accuracy",
                "type" : "Float",
                "value": 2              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name" : "Tem_out",
            "type" : "Integer",
            "value" : 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "statusCode" : {
        "code" : "200",
        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Un Saludo y gracias.

**EDIT01**

Ahora mismo la respuesta que tengo es:

```
[ [ 'S_Temp001', 'Temperatura', 'Tem_int', 'float', 2, 'accuracy', 'Float',2 ] ]
```

Lo estoy guardando en BD de tal forma (funciona correctamente):

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO inver (fiwareServicePath, entityId,  entityType, attrName, attrType, attrValue) VALUES ?";

connection.query(sql, [tmp], function(err, rows) {
          if(err)
          {
            throw err;
            console.log('Error al Conectar' + error);
          }
          else
          {
            res.status(200).json(rows);
          }
        });
```

**Ahora mi duda:** Solo estoy guardando lo que pertenece al `attributes[0]`
Necesito generar otro array separado por , y insertado dentro de [] en el mismo array de tmp es decir algo asi:

```
var tmp= [['S_Temp001', 'Temperatura', 'Tem_int', 'float', 2, 'accuracy',
'Float',2],['S_Temp001', 'Temperatura', 'Tem_out', 'Integer', 1, 'accuracy',
'Float',2]];
```

Para los metadatos he añadido esto en el código que me has proporciondo:

```
   json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].metadatas[0].name,
     json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].metadatas[0].type,
     json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].metadatas[0].value]);
```

Lo necesito así para insertar esta lista en mi base de datos y cada array de dentro en una nueva fila, así se quedaría el ejemplo que te he puesto:

[image: Imagen1]

Supongo que tengo que generar un nuevo for dentro de este `for (var i = 0; i < json["contextResponses"].length; i++)` para que recorra los atributos y los añada como un nuevo array con la estructura que te he comentado antes.

```
var tmp= [['S_Temp001', 'Temperatura', 'Tem_int', 'float', 2, 'accuracy',
    'Float',2],['S_Temp001', 'Temperatura', 'Tem_out', 'Integer', 1, 'accuracy',
    'Float',2]];
```

No se si me he explicado bien.

gracias.

**EDIT02 Solución**

Buenas,

ya he encontrado la solución, la añado por si le puede valer a alguien.

```
  var tmp2 = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < params.contextResponses.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes.length; j++) {
          for (var k = 0; k < params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas.length; k++) {
            console.log("nuevo log antes de petar: " + params["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value);

            tmp2.push([params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.id,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.type,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].name,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].type,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].value,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].name,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].type,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value]);
            console.log("tmp2 --> ",tmp2);
          }
        }
    }
```

Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Estás usando Express? ¿Has puesto el bodyParser?

Comment: Buenas, si estoy usando express y bodyParser.@gugadev

Comment: Acabo de editar el POST por si sirve de ayuda!

Comment: Pregunto donde estás guardando ese JSON? Sería tan facil como almacenarlo en una variable y accederlo mediante **.**

Comment: Mi idea es insertar el JSon que me llega al método en la base de datos, pero solo necesito x campos y no todos.

Comment: trata de no usar variables var en javascript [carga mas en memoria y es mas lento](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21467841/5695795), usa tipo let ademas tambien te invito a [chequear esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript/106067#106067)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  let json = {
    "subscriptionId" : "5a268a598dc68904bbc7b3cf",
    "originator" : "localhost",
    "contextResponses" : [
      {
        "contextElement" : {
          "type" : "Temperatura",
          "isPattern" : "false",
          "id" : "S_Temp001",
          "attributes" : [
            {
              "name" : "Tem_int",
              "type" : "float",
              "value" : 2,
              "metadatas" : [
                {
                  "name" : "accuracy",
                  "type" : "Float",
                  "value": 2              }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name" : "Tem_out",
              "type" : "Integer",
              "value" : 1
            }
          ]
        },
        "statusCode" : {
          "code" : "200",
          "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
        }
      },
      {
        "contextElement" : {
          "type" : "Temperatura",
          "isPattern" : "false",
          "id" : "S_Temp002",
          "attributes" : [
            {
              "name" : "Tem_int1",
              "type" : "float1",
              "value" : 3,
              "metadatas" : [
                {
                  "name" : "accuracy1",
                  "type" : "Floa1t",
                  "value": 3              }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name" : "Tem_out",
              "type" : "Integer",
              "value" : 1
            }
          ]
        },
        "statusCode" : {
          "code" : "200",
          "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  for (let ele in json) {
    //aquí para los que son objetos
    if (typeof(json[ele]) == 'object') {
      eachobject(json[ele]);
    } else {
      console.log('ele --> ', ele, ' - ', json[ele]);
      console.log('typo del ele --> ', typeof(json[ele]));
      console.log(' --------------------- ');
    }
  }

  function eachobject(json) {
    for (let ele in json) {
      if (typeof(json[ele]) == 'object') {
        eachobject(json[ele]);
      } else {
        console.log('ele --> ', ele, ' - ', json[ele]);
        console.log('typo del ele --> ', typeof(json[ele]));
        console.log(' --------------------- ');
      }
    }
  }

  let tmp = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < json["contextResponses"].length; i++) {
    console.log("Attributes --> ", json["contextResponses"][i]);
    tmp.push([json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.id,
         json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.type,
         json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].name,
         json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].type,
         json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].value,
         json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].metadatas[0].name,
         json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].metadatas[0].type,
         json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].metadatas[0].value]);
    console.log("tmp --> ",tmp);
  }
```

Modifique el JSON pensando mas menos en lo que tu necesitas para que lo veas, y al final agregue un for en el que la DATA queda en el formato que tu necesitas (puedes hacerte igual una forma de como hacerlo en caso de que no se exactamente lo que necesitas). Aun así igual avísame en caso de que no sea lo que necesitas y si es posible entregarme un poco mas de detalles para dar una respuesta mas certera.
Espero si aun no habías podido solucionarlo espero esto te sirva o si tienes una forma más fácil de hacer lo pedido comparte :)
PD: Es solo para recorrer el objeto completo si necesitas mas cosas avisa.
PD: Perdón la tardanza no había tenido mucho tiempo y una actualización me dejo la embarrada en mi note xD.

Comment: Hola, estaba realizando dos for anidados etc. Pero esta solución es mejor que la mía, gracias.

Una duda podría Generar un array y dentro de este a su vez otros arrays con la información de X campos del JSON es decir algo asi,

var values = [
       ['id', 'type', 'name', 'type', 'value', 'metadatas'],
       ['id', 'type', 'name', 'type', 'value', 'metadatas'],
       ['id', 'type', 'name', 'type', 'value', 'metadatas'],
       ['id', 'type', 'name', 'type', 'value', 'metadatas'],
       ['id', 'type', 'name', 'type', 'value', 'metadatas']
     ];

Comment: Lo necesito así para insertarlo en my BD una vez que llegue el JSON

Comment: Tengo una duda con respecto a lo último que me preguntaste, imagino que el JSON lo que esta dentro del "contextElement" se repetirá varias veces?.
Por ej.  "contextElement" : { datos 1 }, { datos 2 }, { datos n } 
o es el "contextResponses" el que dentro del array entregara mas de un resultado de "contextElement". (No se si se entendió muy bien).
Por que tu finalmente quieres que quede como value = [['S_Temp001','Temperatura','Tem_int','float',2,['accuracy','float',2]],[...]]

Comment: Buenas, Si como has comentado contextElement siempre es la posicion[0], lo que me interesa es esa información y la los atributos. he probado con esto x.push ( json[ele]); en cada iteracion del bucle para añadir a un array vació, pero no consigo el formato que te he comentado arriba, ya que tengo un método para insertar que tiene esta estructura de ejemplo:
  var sql = "INSERT INTO inver (fiwareServicePath, entityId) VALUES ?";
     var values = [
       ['John', 'Highway 71']
     ];
        connection.query(sql, [values], function(err, rows) {
Gracias por la ayuda de verdad

Comment: no se si con lo que te he comentado he aclaro la duda que tenías, estoy parado en el desarrollo por ese motivo y no se ya como buscar eso... 

Comment: Te sirvió lo que agregue?

Comment: Buenas, la verdad que si me vale lo que me has comentado, solo falta un poco para terminar de afinar lo que necesito.
Ahora mismo tengo me da esta respuesta tmp -->  [ [ 'S_Temp001', 'Temperatura', 'Tem_int', 'float', 2, [ [Object] ] ] ] Edito el POST para enseñarte como tendria que quedar finalmente. Gracias tio de verdad

Comment: trata de no usar variables var en javascript [carga mas en memoria y es mas lento](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21467841/5695795), usa tipo let ademas tambien te invito a [chequear esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript/106067#106067)

Comment: Gracias por la acotación, había escuchado hace poco del tipo let pero aun no lo investigaba.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración con las variables var. @FdoContreras has entendido mas o menos en el EDIT01 del post como tendria que quedar el array?

Comment: Buenas, supongo que no abras tenido tiempo para terminar de ayudarme, ¿has podido mirar el edit del post? Un saludo

Comment: Hola, disculpa la ausencia. Si te fijas el for q esta al final del codigo retorna un arreglo de arreglos con el formato q tu necesitas.
var tmp= [['S_Temp001', 'Temperatura', 'Tem_int', 'float', 2, 'accuracy',
    'Float',2],['S_Temp001', 'Temperatura', 'Tem_out', 'Integer', 1, 'accuracy',
    'Float',2]];

Answer (score 1):

si solo requieres ciertos valores del json, podrias usar destructuring, aquí pongo un ejemplo de lo que me refiero:

```
var json = {
    "name": {
        "first": "Yosuke",
        "family": "Kyra"
    },
    "birth": {
        "year": 1982,
        "month": 12,
        "day": 5
    }
}
// Destructuring
var {name: { family: familyName }, birth: {day: birthDay}} = json
console.log(familyName) // return Kyra
console.log(birthDay) // return 5
```

Mas sobre el tema => https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: otra forma seria obtener las keys del objecto json y con un foreach ir iterando dentro del objecto hasta dar con las keys que contiene los valores que ocupas