# Configuración de sublime text 3

Tags: javascript, html, sublimetext3

Hola amigos cómo configuro el sublime text 3 para que cuando escriba en js y ponga por ejemplo “camp1.value” el “value” se ponga en otro color como en este video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cChuvfRRcYY&t=216s

[image: codigo en sublime text 3]

Gracias!

Comment: cuando declaras elementos del DOM [no uses var , usa const](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript) y antepones un $ , es una de las buenas practicas de JavaScript

Comment: Eso es práctico si es consciente de usar **Ecma Script 6** (ES6).

Answer (score 5):

Para poder tener esos colores, tienes que agregar un tema a sublime, te dejo dos enlaces para que puedas hacerlo.

1. [Como instalar Themes y Color Schemes en Sublime Text 2 y 3](http://www.falconmasters.com/recursos-herramientas/instalar-themes-temas-sublime-text/)
2. [Los 10 mejores temas para Sublime 3](https://scotch.io/@Viclotana/the-10-best-sublime-text-3-themes-of-2017)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, recuerda que para que detecte el tema, el archivo que editas tiene que tener una extension.