# ¿Por qué no funciona este código Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Quiero modificar los datos de un tablero html y solo se cambia el primer dato, los siguientes datos salen como undefined y pos elimina todos los datos una vez se ejecuta el segundo FOR

```js
     var fila1=[2,6,5,4,5,5];
    
    var filacolor1=["blue","yellow","pink","red","yellow","blue"];
    
    
    

    for (var i1 = 0; i1 < 6; i1++) {
        console.info(pos)
        for (let o = 6; o > 0; o--) {
          var pos = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
          rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * o)
          console.log(fila1[pos[rand]])
          console.log(filacolor1[pos[rand]])
          pos.splice(rand, 1);
        }
            
    }
```

Comment: al declara una variable con `var` [javascript te lo colocara al inicio de la funcion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript)

Comment: cambia los var por let

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que esperas que haga el código una vez terminado de ejecutar?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A tu pregunta le falta más información, por ejemplo no indicas con claridad la salida que esperas obtener o el resultado esperado del algoritmo. Lee el artículo y luego edita tu pregunta para mejorar tus probabilidades de obtener buenas respuestas. Un saludo.