# Error con variable global

Tags: javascript, variables-globales

Me podrían indicar ¿que es lo que estoy haciendo mal? Según mi criterio el código debería de correr bien pero el problema es que me da un error en el `element` cuando lo mando a llamar en la primera función para darle un valor, según javascript este debe de llevar una declaración de variable pero esta ya esta puesta como global y ya intente probando con `this`

```
const element = ''

const createSpanTag = () => {
  element = document.createElement('span')
  element.setAttribute('id', `stElement${auto}`)
  element.setAttribute('class', 'stElement')
  return element
}
```

Comment: @JackNavaRow  no me funciono de todas formas :(

Comment: el error te da por que no existe `stElement${auto}`

Comment: mira esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript#answer-106067

Comment: @JackNavaRow sirvio y el stelement esta declarado pero en otro lugar, eso si funciona bien, gracias :)

Comment: tienes un error conceptual,el const defines una variable que no puede ser modificada, al hacer un `document.createElement('span')` estas creando un nuevo objeto y por ello pierde la referencia y te da error de que estas intentando cambiar el valor de una constante

Comment: @JackNavaRow si no se porque no pense en eso, olvide totalmente ese detalle, gracias :)

Comment: que tal si cambias la linea `element = document.createElement('span')` por Object.assign(element ,document.createElement('span'));` el codigo no se comprenderia, esta linea asigna  el objeto a la referencia del elemento; aunque si es por mi cambiara la palabra const por var

Comment: @JackNavaRow es una buena idea, creo que lo implementare

Comment: @JackNavaRow estoy construyendo una libreria y me seria de mucha utilidad que cada vez fuera mas clara

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando replique tu código en mi maquina el error que arrojo fue este:

> Assignment to constant variable.

Este error se produce por que estas usando una `const` para almacenar un dato que luego lo vas a modificar o manipular para mutar. Los datos o variables `const` son inmutables, como su nombre lo dice son valores que se mantienen siempre constantes.

Deberías cambiar tu primera linea por un `let` en vez de un `const` ahora esto te dará otro error que es por el `${auto}` supongo que lo debes tener declarado más arriba de tu código.

```
let element = ''
```

Otra forma de solucionar tu problema seria declarando `const element` dentro del método, con esto podrías asignar sus valores para crear tu elemento sin problemas. Ejemplo:

```
const createSpanTag = () => {
    const element = document.createElement('span')
    element.setAttribute('id', `stElement`)
    element.setAttribute('class', 'stElement${auto}')
    return element
}
```

Espero que te sirva mi respuesta. Saludos !.

**COMO BUENA PRACTICA**

Las variables de tipo `const` globales se acostumbran a colocar en MAYÚSCULA su nombre. Ejemplo:

```
const ELEMENT_SPAN = ''
```

Comment: de igual forma puedo hacer `Object.assign(element ,document.createElement('span'));` la variable no muto solo asigno los atributos al objeto element (esto esta explicado en la pregunta var let const o nada)

Comment: Pero lo correcto seria usar un let y no un const

Comment: lo correcto seria usar usar const dentro del metodo.

Comment: Si también puede. Lo agregare a mi respuesta.