# Envío de datos desde un Form a servidor ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs, express

estoy trabajando en una aplicación web sencilla, pero es el primero contacto que tengo con un servidor nodeJs utilizando ExpressJs...
Ya logré obtener los datos utilizando un método get y req.query directo desde la URL pero quisiera saber cómo obtener los datos desde un formulario.

Este es el código que tengo en el servidor:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const server  = http.createServer(app);
app.use(express.static("static"))

var arreglo=[
{no:0, numControl:"", nombre:"", paterno: "", materno:"", carrera:""},
]

app.get("/", function(req ,res){
    res.json({datos: arreglo});
});

app.get("/add", function(req ,res){
    console.log(req.query);
    let alumno={

        no:arreglo.length+1, 
        numControl:req.query.numControl, 
        nombre: req.query.nombre, 
        paterno: req.query.paterno, 
        materno: req.query.materno, 
        carrera: req.query.carrera
    }
    arreglo.push(alumno)
    console.log(arreglo)
    res.end();
})

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Servidor activo");
})
```

En el archivo html coloqué el formulario de la siguiente manera:

```
<body>
    <div id="app" class="app">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Num. Control</th>
                    <th>Nombre Completo</th>
                    <th>Carrera</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-if="lista.length==0">
                    <td colspan="5">Aún no hay elementos registrados</td>
                </tr>
                <tr v-else v-for="(a, i) in lista">
                    <td>{{ a.no }}</td>
                    <td>{{ a.numControl }}</td>
                    <td>{{ nombreCompleto(a) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ a.carrera }}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="data"><br></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

        <div id="botones" class="botones">
            <button class="btn">Agregar</button>
            <button>Eliminar</button>
            <button>Modificar</button>
        </div><br>  
        <div>
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label>Nombre Completo:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" id="nomComp">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Numero de Control:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="NumeroControl" id="NumCon" value="">
                </div>  
                <div>
                    <label>Carrera</label>
                    <select name="carreras" id="carr">
                        <option value="siste" name="siste">Ing.Sistemas</option>
                        <option value="meca" name="meca">Ing. Mecatronica</option>
                        <option value="ambi" name="ambi">Ing. Ambiental</option>
                        <option value="elec" name="elec">Ing. Electronica</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="vueJS/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="vueJS/vue-resource.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="serverCRUDalumnos.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Una disculpa si tengo errores en tabulación o simplemente es una pregunta absurda, pero soy un programador poco experimentado y me gustaría aprender.

Comment: ¿Quieres usar AJAX o simplemente que el formulario se envíe? Si es lo segundo, tienes que añadir en la etiqueta form la URL y el método (GET, supongo). Además tendrás que modificar tu código en Node porque recibirás un `form-data` no un JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, si vas a usar [Express](http://expressjs.com/) no es necesario usar el módulo `http` de Node, (a menos que trabajes directamente sobre el mismo, como lo hace [`socket.io`](https://socket.io/), por ejemplo).

En segundo lugar, si usas Node (imagino que usas al menos Node 8.0 o superior), evita usar `var` para declarar tus variables, es preferible siempre usar `const` y `let`.

Puedes ver: [var, let, const… o nada en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript)

Por otro lado, puedes enviar los datos del formulario directamente usando el evento [`submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) del formulario o mediante un elemento [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/button) o [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input) de tipo `submit`.

También, tal como comenta @PabloLozano, puedes hacer uso de [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) para realizar el envío del formulario desde el [frontend](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_y_back-end) hacia el [backend](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_y_back-end).

**Backend**

Ahora, lo que necesitas es implementar una forma de recibir los datos del mismo en el lado del servidor (backend), y para ello debes crear un `endpoint` en Express.

La ruta que implementes es cosa tuya, existen diversidad de opiniones al respecto, y cada una expone los motivos del porqué hacerlo así.

Supongamos que la ruta que va a servir de `endpoint` es:

```
'/api/alumnos/add'
```

En esta ruta vamos a recibir los datos de un formulario.

Para que esto funcione, debemos establecer el método `http` que manejará dicha ruta, y debemos decidir cómo vamos a leer los datos.

Para este ejemplo, vamos usar el método [`POST`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST), y leeremos los datos que se envían en el cuerpo (`body`) de la solicitud.

Para poder leer los datos que vienen en el cuerpo de la solicitud, debemos usar un `middleware` de Express para analizar (`parse`) su contenido.

A partir de la versión 4.16.0 Express dispone de los siguientes métodos middleware:

- [`express.json()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json) que nos permite analizar el cuerpo de la solicitud con contenido JSON.
- [`express.urlencoded()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded) que nos permite analizar el cuerpo de la solicitud con contenido `urlencoded`.

Con esto ya tenemos todo lo necesario para armar nuestro `endpoint` básico:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static('static'));

// depósito de datos temporal

let alumnos = []; // <- se inicia vacío con la aplicación

//rutas o endpoints
app.post('/api/alumnos/add', (req, res, next) => {
  const alumno = req.body;
  if(!alumno) {
    return res.status(400).json({error: 'No hay datos'});
  }
  alumno.no = alumnos.length + 1;
  console.log(alumno);
  alumnos.push(alumno);
  // podemos enviar el array de alumnos, así por cada vez que accedemos a este
  // a este endpoint vamos viendo los datos almacenados
  return res.status(200).json(alumnos);
});

// la siguiente ruta capturará todos los métodos http a cualquier ruta que no haya
// sido declarada anteriormente
app.all('/', (req, res, next) => {
  return res.status(200).json({message: 'Servidor listo'})
});

//iniciamos el servidor
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.info(`Servidor escuchando en puerto: ${port}`);
});
```

Ya tenemos listo el `backend` con nuestro `endpoint` esperando datos en la ruta acordada.

**Frontend**

Aquí existen infinidad de opciones, aunque veo que usas [`Vue.js`](https://vuejs.org/). No voy a entrar en detalles del uso de librerías o frameworks, ya que tu pregunta va más orientada a envío de datos de un formulario, lo cual existe antes que toda esta infinidad de frameworks y librerías vieran la luz.

Vamos a crear un formulario sencillo con los datos que va a recibir nuestro servidor de Express.

En tu pregunta tienes un modelo de ficha de alumno en un formulario, y eso es lo que haremos, usando simple y puro `html`:

```html
<!--
  El siguiente formulario envía una solicitud: "POST", con un tipo de datos: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  a la ruta: "/api/alumnos/add" del host o dominio.
-->
<form id="ficha" action="/api/alumnos/add" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="nombre">Nombre Completo:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="nombre" name="nombre">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="control">Numero de Control:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="control" name="control">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="carrera">Carrera:</label>
    <select id="carr" name="carrera">
      <option value="" name="siste">--Seleccione:--</option>
      <option value="siste" name="siste">Ing.Sistemas</option>
      <option value="meca" name="meca">Ing. Mecatronica</option>
      <option value="ambi" name="ambi">Ing. Ambiental</option>
      <option value="elec" name="elec">Ing. Electronica</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Puedes leer en el comentario del código anterior lo siguiente:

- El método `http` del formulario se establece a "post".
- El tipo MIME de los datos del formulario se establece como "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
- La ruta o `endpoint` a la que se envían los datos es "/api/alumnos/add", la cual pertenece al host o dominio.

Un aspecto importante: el elemento `<input>` de tipo `submit` tiene un atributo `value="Enviar"` y no `name="Enviar"` como lo tienes en tu pregunta. La razón de esto es muy sencilla, te animo a que hagas la prueba con ambos valores y veas la diferencia.

Con esto ya tienes la forma de enviar datos de un formulario web hacia tu servidor de Express.

Si deseas un ejemplo, puedes ver el siguiente [repositorio](https://github.com/virtualkur2/express-submit-form-example) de Github, donde implemento todo lo anterior.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Sé que tengo varios errores en el código, te agradezco por las observaciones y recomendaciones, estoy estudiando apenas la carrera de Ing. Sistemas y la programación siempre es lo que más me ha costado entender. Sólo una pregunta, podrías explicarme cómo se haría el frontend utilizando Vue.js? Mi maestro quiere que a fuerza sea con VueJS y vueResource. Saludos y gracias nuevamente!!

Comment: Me marcó un error cuando intenté ejecutar el servidor:
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\savan\Documents\ITSTB - JOSE TEJEDA\7mo Semestre\Interfaces Web\Unidad 1\web\\CRUD\ServidorAlum.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

Comment: El error marca una barra invertida de más por algún lado, por favor verifica eso: `...\web\\CRUD\...`. Es por eso que te salta el mismo. Verifica tus rutas en el archivo `package.json` y en cómo realizas los `requiere()`. Saludos