# Problema retorno objeto funcion javaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy empezando con javaScript y tengo la siguiente funcion, la cual quiero que devuelva el objeto almacenado en la variable nuevaCuenta mediante el return:

```
// metodo para guardar los datos de la nueva cuenta
    function cuentaNueva() {
        // obtenemos el valor de los campos
        var cuenta = document.getElementById("numeroCuentaNueva").value;
        var nombre = document.getElementById("nombreCuentaNueva").value;
        var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidadCuentaNueva").value;
        // comprobamos que los campos no estan vacios
        if (cuenta == "") {
            //mostramos el mensaje
            alert("El campo cuenta no puede estar vacio");
        } else if (nombre == "") {
            // mostramos el mensaje
            alert("El campo nombre no puede estar vacio");
        } else if (cantidad == "") {
            // mostramos el mensaje
            alert("El campo cantidad no puede estar vacio");
        } else {
            // hacemos el ingreso de la cuenta
            // creamos una instancia de la clase y guardamos el valor de campo cuenta, nombre y cantidad de la cuenta nueva creada
            var nuevaCuenta = new Cuenta(cuenta, nombre, cantidad);
            // variable para obtener el nombre el desplegable donde cargaremos los datos
            var sele = opener.document.getElementById("cuentas");
            //Creamos la opcion
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            // metemos el texto en la opcion 
            option.innerHTML = cuenta;
            // metemos la opcion en el select
            sele.appendChild(option);
            // motramos el mensaje
            alert("Cuenta creada con exito");
            // cerramos la ventana
            close();
        }
        // retornamos el objeto
        return nuevaCuenta;
    }
```

El caso esque cuando intento guardar el contenido en una variable para utilizarla en otra funcion no me funciona, no hace nada, podrian decirme en que me equivoco.
Ejemplo de llamada a la funcion para almacenar en la variable
var cue = cuentaNueva().getNumero();

El codigo del objeto es  el siguiente:

```
class Cuenta {
    // declaramos el constructor
    constructor(numero, nombre, cantidad) {
        this.numero = numero;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    // metodo para obtener el numero
    getNumero() {
        return this.numero
    }

    // metodo para obtener el nombre
    getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    // metodo para obtener la cantidad
    getCantidad() {
        return this.cantidad;
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías poner el código del objeto cuenta para saber por que no retorna el objeto

Comment: ya esta puesto el codigo

Comment: Una pista: no uses `var`, usa `let` y seguramente te darás cuenta de lo que pasa. Seguramente estás devolviendo `undefined`

Comment: Supongo que el problema lo está dando porque declaras "nuevaCuenta" dentro del "else".

Comment: cambio var por let en la instancia es a lo que te refieres

Comment: Cambia todas, deberías no usar var, desde ES2015 es mejor no usarla nunca: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript/106067#106067

Comment: pero entonces Pablo como se deberia de hacer para devolver el objeto con la funcion

Answer (score 0):

Analicemos tu función de manera rápida:

```
function cuentaNueva() {
    ... // código aquí
    if (cuenta == "") {
        //mostramos el mensaje
        alert("El campo cuenta no puede estar vacio");
    } else if (nombre == "") {
        // mostramos el mensaje
        alert("El campo nombre no puede estar vacio");
    } else if (cantidad == "") {
        // mostramos el mensaje
        alert("El campo cantidad no puede estar vacio");
    } else {
        ... // código aquí
        var nuevaCuenta = new Cuenta(cuenta, nombre, cantidad);
        ... // más código aquí
        close();
    }
    // retornamos el objeto
    return nuevaCuenta;
}
```

Si cualquiera de las condiciones previas se cumplen, muestras un alert y tu función no inicializará la variable nuevaCuenta, devolviendo `undefined`.

Si usásemos para declarar la variable `let` en lugar de `var`, el propio compilador te avisaría de que hay algo raro en tu código:

```js
function cuentaNueva(cuenta) {
    
    if (cuenta == "") {
       
    } else {
        let nuevaCuenta = 1; //por poner algo
    }

    return nuevaCuenta;
}

cuentaNueva();
```

Por tanto cuentaNueva sólo devuelve una `Cuenta` cuando todo *va bien*, y `undefined` si algo es incorrecto. Esto no es malo de por sí, puedes comprobarlo después:

```
let cuenta= cuentaNueva();
if (cuenta) {
  cuenta.getNombre();
} else {
  console.log('No se pudo crear');
}
```

Comment: Pero entonces como se deberia de hacer, esque no encuentro nada y ya estoy "cegado"