# ¿Cómo hacer que cada fila de la tabla tenga un color diferente?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una tabla pero necesito que cada una de las filas sea de un color distinto, intercalandose un color con el otro, esto con la finalidad de facilitar la lectura. Ojo, solo quiero usar dos colores (gris oscuro y gris claro). Por lo cual pense que hacer un arreglo a traves de *getelementsbytagname* y hacer un ciclo `for` en el cual se verifica si el número es par o impar para poder hacer el patrón de colores. Les dejo el código acá

```js
   var x = document.getElementsByTagName("TH");
   for(i = 0; i <= x; i++){
    if(i%2 == 1){
     x[i].style.backgroundColor = "#888888";
    }
    else{
     x[i].style.backgroundColor = "#DDDDDD";
    }
   }
```

```css
   table, tr, th{
    border-style: solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
   }
```

```html
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th>Pizza Slice</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Hamburger</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Hot Dog</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Corn Dog</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Sandwish</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Nachos</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Salad</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Ice cream</th>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que estás teniendo? ¿Que no se te ponen los colores que requieres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes un pequeño error en la sintaxis de tu ciclo, ya que debes especificar el `length` de *x*; además ten en cuenta que el contador de la variable comienza en 0, por lo que tu comparación de `i <= x.length` te dará un error

```
for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   //codigo
}
```

Funcionando perfecto

```js
const x = document.getElementsByTagName("TH");

for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   if(i%2 == 1) {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "#888888";
   }
   else {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "#DDDDDD";
   }
}
```

```css
table, tr, th {
   border-style: solid;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>PizzaSlice</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Hamburger</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Hot Dog</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Corn Dog</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Sandwish</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Nachos</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Salad</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Ice cream</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas

Comment: si ve esto uno de nuestro mod(AlvaroMontoro) te dijera que solo con css se puede hacer xD

Comment: Es que Alvaro y tú están a otro nivel, aún no llego al Olimpo pero para allá apuntamos jajajajaa...

Comment: Gracias, solo me queda una duda, porque usas la palabra const en lugar de var cuando declaras x? cual es la diferencia?

Comment: me base más que nada en ES6 y uso los cambios de esa versión; `var` esta un poco obsoleto y se está utilizando `const` para variables que que no son reasignables, es un tema largo así que te dejo un poco de [info](https://cybmeta.com/var-let-y-const-en-javascript) para que la revises :)

Comment: al usar var generalmente se queda en el DOM te invito a [leer esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript) donde uno de nuestros expertos explica con peras y manzana mejor

Comment: Aprendan CSS por favor, eviten cargar el javascript por algo así... Aquí un buen sitio para aprender: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/

Answer (score 2):

Con Javascript, lo mejor sería hacerlo directamente con las filas:

```
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            if(i % 2){
                x[i].style.backgroundColor = "#888888";
            }
            else{
                x[i].style.backgroundColor = "#DDDDDD";
            }
        }
```

**Solución solo CSS:** Usa nth-child con sus reglas even (pares) y odd (nones)

```
table tr:nth-child(even) { background:#c0c0c0; }
table tr:nth-child(odd) { background:#808080; }
```

Referencia: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: ¿Y si lo quisiera hacer solo con javascript, cómo sería?

Comment: que tal si agregas el ejemplo completo con html/css , vamos puedes dar una respuesta de calidad, con el ejemplo del usuario

Answer (score 0):

Bueno primero te dejo un ejemplo funcional, segundo cuando recorrías **X** no estabas recorriendo un array estabas recorriendo un objeto por eso nunca ingresaba solo agrega el `length` y funciono.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table, tr, th{
                border-style: solid;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Pizza Slice</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Hamburger</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Hot Dog</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Corn Dog</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Sandwish</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Nachos</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Salad</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Ice cream</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>

            var x = document.getElementsByTagName("TH");
            
             for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
                if(i%2 == 1){
                   x[i].style.backgroundColor = "#888888";
                }
                else{
                   x[i].style.backgroundColor = "#DDDDDD";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edición**: Ahora puede hacer solo con **CSS** de la siguiente forma, te dejo un ejemplo funcional:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table, tr, th{
                border-style: solid;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            
            table tr:nth-child(even) { background:#c0c0c0; }
            table tr:nth-child(odd) { background:#808080; }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Pizza Slice</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Hamburger</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Hot Dog</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Corn Dog</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Sandwish</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Nachos</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Salad</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Ice cream</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
      
    </body>
</html>
```