# Al declarar una variable dentro de un if es considerada global scope?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda 
Tengo el siguiente segmento de codigo

```
var edad = 16;
  if (edad === 18) {
    var esAdulto = true;
  } else {
    esAdulto = false;
  }
  console.log("..Es Adulto: " + esAdulto);
```

Mi pregunta es al declarar una variable var dentro de una sentencia if o bloque {} es considerado global scope ?

No deberia tirar error variable no definida al tratrar de imprimir "esAdulto"
ya que se encuentra dentro de un bloque de codigo de otro nivel.

Scope: El ambito de un variable (llamado en ingles "scope") en la zona del programa
en la que se define una varible
Javascript define 2 ambitos Glogal y funcion o **bloque**

la variable no debe destruirse al salir de un bloque de codigo?

```
  if (Condicion) {
    // Bloque de codigo encerrado por {}
    //
    // ... fin de codigo
  } else {
    // Otro bloque de codigo
    // ... fin de codigo
  }
```

Comment: Es local esAdulto. Te recomiendo crear esa misma variable, fuera de toda condición, sin asignarle ningún valor, y luego cuando la condición se cumpla, setees un valor a tal variable y la retornes para asegurarte.
esAdutlo = 1;

Answer (score -3):

1. Todo lo que este dentro de un bloque de codigo {}, es considerado variable local.
2. Si la variable esta fuera del bloque de codigo, es considerado variable global.

Nota: Esto se debe a que la variable local NO puede acceder hacia fuera, pero las variables globales si pueden estar afuera y dentro.

Ejemplo (será un ejemplo un poco raro, pero te dará la idea hehehe): Tu órganos internos del cuerpo (**variable local**) no pueden ver lo que esta afuera, pero tus ojos (**variable global**), pueden ver lo que esta dentro de tu cuerpo, sea este cortando el tejido de la piel, para poder acceder a tus organos.

En cuanto a las condicionales, dependiendo donde y como lo implementes puede ser local o global, me explico:

si dentro de tu condicional IF (como el ejempo anterior):

**var edad** entiendo que seria tu variable global, y las variables dentro, osea, **esAdulto** , seria tu variable local. **pero como estas esperando una respuesta**, después de validar la condicional y está dentro de tu bloque de código, este te permite imprimir el resultado en tu console.log.

Si salieras de ese bloque de código e intentaras crear otro y llamar a ese resultado anterior en el nuevo bloque, NO funcionaria.

Espero que está respuesta, allá podido aclarar tus dudas. También la mejor forma de comprobar algo, es haciendo la prueba. A veces nuestra lógica no es igual o no esta a la par en programación hehehhee....

Lógica de programación te puede ayudar a reforzar estos conceptos, siempre y cuando practiques.

Comment: Ambas son globales si no están metidas en una función. Prueba a hacer `if(true){var x =0;}` y veras como puedes acceder desde fuera. Aquí se explica muy bien: [var, let, const… o nada en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/106067/128699)

Comment: Exacto, por eso le dije que "dependiendo como y donde lo implemente puede ser local o global"...

Comment: Me parecen conceptos equivocados, checa aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var