# Como comparar correctamente 2 valores con Javascript o Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Resulta que estoy tratando de validar que un input no sea mayor a otro pero no funciona correctamente

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
        function enviar() {
            let totalAnopheles = $('#totalAnopheles').val()
            let totalZancudos = $('#totalZancudos').val()
            if (totalAnopheles > totalZancudos) {
                console.log("error")
            } else {
                console.log('correcto')
            }

        }

    </script>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="totalZancudos">Total Zancudos:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal" id="totalZancudos" name="totalZancudos" required="required">
        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="totalAnopheles">Total Anopheles:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal" id="totalAnopheles" name="totalAnopheles" required="required">
        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="enviar()">click</button>
```

la idea es que wl segundo input (Anopheles) no puede ser mayor a Zancudos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás capturando los valores de los `input`. Puedes usar `val()` para ello, ya que estás usando jQuery.

Por otra parte, si usas `let` el dato se quedará siempre con el primer valor que tenía el `input` cuando llamaste a la función. Convendría usar `var`, porque así el dato se evaluará con el valor que tenga en ese momento.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
        function enviar() {
            var totalAnopheles = $('#totalAnopheles').val();
            var totalZancudos = $('#totalZancudos').val();
            if (totalAnopheles > totalZancudos) {
                console.log("error")
            } else {
                console.log('correcto')
            }

        }

    </script>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="totalZancudos">Total Zancudos:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal" id="totalZancudos" name="totalZancudos" required="required">
        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="totalAnopheles">Total Anopheles:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal" id="totalAnopheles" name="totalAnopheles" required="required">
        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="enviar()">click</button>
```

Comment: ok pequeño detalle que olvidé, pero siempre me da error, si por ejemplo ingreso totalZancudos = 1, totalAnopheles = 10 dara error, pero siluego cambio totalZancudos =121 ,totalAnopheles=22 siempre cae en error

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez revisa la edición, debes cambiar `let` por `var` porque aquel te deja el valor fijo (el de la primera vez que se invocó la función). Sobre la diferencia de modificadores, [esto puede ayudar a entenderlo mejor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/106042/29967).

Comment: Gracias veo que eso resuelve

Comment: Creo que esta afirmación es incorrecta: *Por otra parte, si usas `let` el dato se quedará siempre con el primer valor que tenía el input cuando llamaste a la función*. Yo lo revisaría, porque no es exactamente eso lo que sucede.

Answer (score 2):

Un pequeño detalle: al obtener con `.val()` los valores de cada campo, estás obteniendo cada valor como string (pese a que utilizás `<input type="number">`). Dos formas de convertir el valor que obtuviste a Number son:

- Anteponer `+` (como lo dejo en el código),
- convertirlo con `parseInt()`

quedando como resultado final:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
        function enviar() {
            //ambos valores convertidos a Number:
            let totalAnopheles = +$('#totalAnopheles').val();
            let totalZancudos = +$('#totalZancudos').val();
            if (totalAnopheles > totalZancudos) {
                console.log("error")
            } else {
                console.log('correcto')
            }
        }
    </script>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="totalZancudos">Total Zancudos:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal" id="totalZancudos" name="totalZancudos" required="required">
        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="totalAnopheles">Total Anopheles:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal" id="totalAnopheles" name="totalAnopheles" required="required">
        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="enviar()">click</button>
```