# ¿Cómo hago para que cuando termine de correr la función con el primer parámetro, la variable resultado se reinicie en 0?

Tags: javascript

Cuando corro la función con `sumatoriaHasta(4)` me arroja como resultado 6 (correcto), pero cuando corro inmediatamente `sumatoriaHasta(5)` obtengo de resultado la 16, es decir 10 (el resultado correcto) + 6 el resultado anterior. Necesitaria que la variable resultado se me reinicie en cero cada vez que la función se vuelva a correr.

```
var resultado = 0;
function sumatoriaHasta(x){
    for( let i=0; i<x;i++){
        resultado = resultado + i;
    }
    return resultado;
}
sumatoriaHasta(4);
sumatoriaHasta(5);
```

Answer (score 5):

El problema es que declaras la variable resultado fuera de la función.

La solución sería la siguiente:

```js
function sumatoriaHasta(x){
var resultado = 0;
    for( let i=0; i<x;i++){
        resultado = resultado + i;
    }
    return resultado;
}
console.log(sumatoriaHasta(4));
console.log(sumatoriaHasta(5));
```

Answer (score 4):

Creo que sería importante que leyeras acerca de [var, let, const y nada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript/106052#106052), las variables que puedes declarar en Javascript

Ahí la variable esta declarada para todo el documento, si quieres declararla solo para la función declárala dentro de la función

```
function sumatoriaHasta(x){
    let resultado = 0;
    for( let i=0; i<x;i++){
        resultado = resultado + i;
    }
    return resultado;
}
sumatoriaHasta(4);
sumatoriaHasta(5);
```

He cambiado `let` por `var` dado que eso asegura que dicha variable solo viva dentro de la función.

Comment: Vaya, que rapido :c

Comment: Tienes razón, sin embargo consideraría buena práctica empezar a diferenciar los tipos de variable que existen en JS, de cualquier forma como dices, com ambos funciona correctamente.

Comment: Sr1871, no será "He cambiado `var` por `let`..."?