# Sumar numbers en ts

Tags: angular, typescript

Buenas estoy intentando sumar dos variables pero el resultado es NaN parece muy simple pero no encuentro el problema alguien sabe alguna solucion?

```
let array = localStorage.getItem('cart');
this.products = JSON.parse(array);
var products;
for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
  var perProduct = this.products[i]["costPrice"] * this.products[i]["quantity"] ;
  products = perProduct + products;
}
```

Ejemplo del JSON:

```js
0:
PLU: ""
buttonText: "baguett artesana"
color: "#BACDE2"
costPrice: 0.7
familyId: 1
id: 1
name: "baguett artesana"
quantity: 3
```

Comment: ¿Has depurado tus variables? ¿Seguro recibes los valores correctos? ¿Qué te devuelve `parseInt` y/o `parseFloat` sobre tus variables? Sin ver el tipo de datos que pretendes *sumar* es difícil darte una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Si lo he hecho son tipo number probé a hacer el parseFloat ya que son decimales pero me sigue dando NaN.

Comment: ¿Cabe la posibilidad que `var products` esté *pisando* a `this.products`?

Comment: Deberías poner un ejemplo del JSON.

Comment: Ya esta añadido, no tiene nada que ver var products con this.product el error esta con los tipos de variable

Answer (score 1):

Tienes lo siguiente:

```js
let array = [0,1,2];
var products; //declarada, pero no inicializada

for (let i = 0; i < array.length;i++) {
  products = products + array[i]; //undefined + n == NaN
}

console.log(products);
```

Por tanto, lo que necesitas es inicializar esa variable a 0:

```
let products = 0;
```

Te aconsejo no usar `var`, puedes leer sobre el tema en esta otra [pregunta/respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript/106067#106067)