# Variable is not defined en bucle do-while

Tags: javascript

funcion length en javascript.  me da error al contar los  numeros
y sale del bucle meta la cantidad de digitos que meta

```
do{
let num=prompt("introduce 5 numeros");
}while(num.length!=5)
```

Comment: Y el error es...? Lee [ask].

Comment: Recuerda que `let` tiene alcance de bloque, por lo tanto la declaración de `num` dentro del bucle está aislada y es diferente de la variable `num` que aparece en tu sentencia `while`. Supongo que el error en consola es: `Uncaught ReferenceError: num is not defined` . Una opción es declarar tu variable fuera del bucle (antes de hacer `do` y otra opción es declarar la variable con `var`, ejemplo: `var num = prompt( ... );`. En todo caso, una lectura a [*var, let const o nada en Javascript*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript) no viene mal. Saludos

Comment: hola saludos gracias en verdad que  si pero lo he probado y no me funciona de igual forma var y no me funciona nose por que saludos

Comment: Y cual es el error?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta declarando la variable `num` fuera del bloque  `do/while`:

```js
    let num = "";
    do{
      num = prompt("introduce 5 numeros");
    } while( num.length != 5 )
```

Estas declarando la variable `num` dentro del bloque `do` por lo que al momento de verificar si `num` difiere de 5 entonces lanza el error de que `num` no esta definido.

Comment: muchisimas muchisimas gracias de verdad de verdad que si muchas gracias.... pude reolsverlo gracias ti muchas gracias y a todos los que me ayudaron saludos