# Optimizar código para formatear diferencia entre dos fechas

Tags: javascript, json

Quisiera saber cómo puedo optimizar mi código. Lo que pasa es que tengo la siguiente respuesta

```
  { index:'1',id: 'Caso 1', date : '2020-04-03T16:31:45.000' },
  { index:'2',id: 'Caso 2', date : '2022-06-24T16:31:45.000' },
  { index:'3',id: 'Caso 3', date: '2019-11-03T16:31:45.000' }
```

Toda esa información se va a una mat-table, pero necesito obtener los días de diferencia que existen de la columna date hasta el día de su consulta (ejemplo el día de hoy). Lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

```js
var rows = [];
var itemNew = [{
    index: '1',
    id: 'Caso 1',
    date: '2020-04-03T16:31:45.000'
  },
  {
    index: '2',
    id: 'Caso 2',
    date: '2022-06-24T16:31:45.000'
  },
  {
    index: '3',
    id: 'Caso 3',
    date: '2019-11-03T16:31:45.000'
  }
]

//Aplique el formato a la fecha actual de la siguiente manera
var fecha_inicio = new Date();
var year = fecha_inicio.getFullYear();
var month = (fecha_inicio.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
var day = fecha_inicio.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
var fecha_com = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
var fechaPrincipal = new Date(fecha_com).getTime();

//Recorri cierta parte de los datos ya que no me interesa poner todos los datos, sino algunos en especificos
itemNew.forEach(element => {
  var f_element = new Date(element.date);
  var yElement = f_element.getFullYear();
  var mElement = (f_element.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
  var dElement = f_element.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
  var fComElement = yElement + '-' + mElement + '-' + dElement;
  var fechaRestar = new Date(fComElement).getTime();
  var dif = fechaPrincipal - fechaRestar;
  var rs = (dif / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); // (1000*60*60*24) --> milisegundos -> segundos -> minutos -> horas -> días
  var temp = [element.index, element.date, rs];
  rows.push(temp);
});
// Agregado para ver el resultado
console.log(rows);
```

Lo que siento que está mal es cómo hago el formateo ya que aunque son pocos datos que se manejan pues creo que no es lo más óptimo, entonces no sé cómo podría cambiar para optimizarlo y dejar de hacer todo el formateo, para que obtenga la siguiente respuesta:

```
[ [ '1', '2020-04-03T16:31:45.000', 840 ],
  [ '2', '2022-06-24T16:31:45.000', 28 ],
  [ '3', '2019-11-03T16:31:45.000', 992 ] ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al principio, no me había quedado clara la intención de tu pregunta, pero aquí van unas sugerencias para mejorar el código:

- Evita el uso de `var` para declarar variables, es mejor usar `let` o `const`. Puedes leer [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/106042/54039) y sus respuestas para saber más
- Estás declarando muchas variables que, al final, no son necesarias para realizar los cálculos
- Puedes tomar los milisegundos transcurridos desde el 1-ene/1970 hasta la fecha actual con `Date.now()`
- Posteriormente, usas el objeto `Date()` y el método `getTime()` para obtener los milisegundos de la fecha que deseas comparar
- En general, evita crear variables cuando no sean necesarias, a veces pueden generar confusión en lugar de hacer más claro el código

```js
let rows = [];
let itemNew = [{
    index: '1',
    id: 'Caso 1',
    date: '2020-04-03T16:31:45.000'
  },
  {
    index: '2',
    id: 'Caso 2',
    date: '2022-06-24T16:31:45.000'
  },
  {
    index: '3',
    id: 'Caso 3',
    date: '2019-11-03T16:31:45.000'
  }
]

// Obtener fecha actual en milisegundos desde 1-ene/1970
let hoy = Date.now();

// Recorrer arreglo
itemNew.forEach(element => {
    // Calcular diferencia usando el objeto Date sin variables intermedias
    let dif = hoy - (new Date(element.date)).getTime();
    // Math.round() para redondear y obtener entero
    // (1000*60*60*24) --> milisegundos -> segundos -> minutos -> horas -> días
    let rs = Math.round(dif / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), 0);
    // No se requiere otra variable para crear el nuevo arreglo
    rows.push([element.index, element.date, rs]);
});
// Agregado para ver el resultado
console.log(rows);
```

Comment: Es lo que no entendía, ya que vi algo similar y tuve que ir partiendo en pequeños bloques, que si cumplen la función, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Puedes simplificarlo usando Luxon:

(Dentro de tu bucle)

```
const diff = luxon.DateTime.now().diff(
    luxon.DateTime.fromISO(element2.date),
    'days'
);

rows.push([element2.index, element2.date, diff.values.days]);
```

Comment: Checa re eso, ya que para mi es algo nuevo, gracias por aporte

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer el código más limpio, puedes utilizar la librería de [moment](https://momentjs.com/), la cual tiene un método `diff`: este puede darte la diferencia de las fechas.

Aquí dejé el código que hice:

```
const moment = require('moment');

const today = moment();
itemNew.forEach(element2 => {
   const diff = today.diff(moment(element2.date), 'days');
   rows.push([element2.index, element2.date, diff]);
})
console.log(rows);
```

> Como lo haces está genial, entiendes cómo funcionan las fechas, pero antes estaría genial intentar buscar alguna librería que pueda simplificar el trabajo.

Comment: Estuve algo de tiempo investigando, y ya de ahí fue como lo hice, y si vi muchos comentarios para hacer uso de esta librería, y por ultimo gracias!

Comment: No está demás aclarar que en la propia documentación [el equipo de Moment.js recomienda ya no utilizar tal librería](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status).

Comment: Es interesante no habia mirado esto, gracias por la informacion, igual recomiendas esta libreria, Link: https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon

Comment: No puedo recomendar a ciegas :)

Comment: jaja perdon, *recomiendan* en el link que mandaste los de moment recomiendan la libreria de luxon