# Obtener arreglo a partir de otro, evitando espacios vacíos

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente arreglo de elementos:

```
const item= [{name : a, color : white, status : offline},
            {name : b, color : red, status : offline},
            {name : c, color : yellow, status : online},
            {name : e, color : green, status : online}]
```

Necesito crear un nuevo objeto a partir de éste, pero que solo contenga el 'nombre' de los elementos que tengan su status 'online', que sea dinámico pues no sé cuántos elementos más se puedan insertar.

Aquí mi código:

```
let newItem={};
let objLen=Object.keys(item).length;
for(const i=0;i<=objLen;i++){
 if([item.status][i] === 'online' && [item.status][i] != 'offline'){
  newItem[i]=[item.name][i]
 }
}
console.log(newItem);
```

El problema es que newItem me regresa ésto:

```
newItem= [{},
         {},
         {name : c},
         {name : e}]
```

Y quisiera que solo me los regresara así:

```
newItem= [{name : c},
         {name : e}]
```

Comment: Por cierto: no utilices `const` en el `for` (de hecho debería darte un error). Revisa [var, let, const... o nada en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combinando **[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** y **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**, puedes lograr lo que quieres

```js
const data = [
  { name : 'a', color : 'white', status : 'offline' },
  { name : 'b', color : 'red', status : 'offline' },
  { name : 'c', color : 'yellow', status : 'online' },
  {name : 'e', color : 'green', status : 'online' }
]

const list = data.filter(x => x.status === 'online').map(x => ({ name: x.name }))

console.log(list)
```

y listo!

Nos comentas si tienes dudas o no es lo que necesitabas :)