# Contar cuántos valores del vector son mayores que la media

Tags: javascript

Recién empiezo con Javascript y digamos que me cuesta plantear y optimizar las tareas.

Bueno, lo que hice con ese enunciado fue lo siguiente:

```js
var a=[1,3,50,7,9,20,12,87];
var suma=0;
var mayor=0;
var i;

 for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
 suma=suma+a[i];
 }

 var media=suma/a.length;

 alert(`La media es ${media}`);

 for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
   if(a[i]>media) {
   mayor=mayor+1;
   }
 }

alert(`Hay ${mayor} números superiores a la media`);
```

El resultado en principio está bien, pero pienso que debería mejorar el código.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes! Te recomiendo completar el [tour] y leer [ask] (aunque considero que esta pregunta está bien formulada)

Comment: Si la respuesta de Pablo te ha sido útil, no olvides [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El código se podría escribir de otro modo, usando [los métodos que tiene la clase `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), pero no sería más eficiente en ejecución:

```js
const numeros = [1, 3, 50, 7, 9, 20, 12, 87];
//reduce el array a un único valor, usando 0 como acumulado inicial
const funcionSuma = (acumulado, numero) => acumulado + numero;
const media = numeros.reduce(funcionSuma, 0) / numeros.length;

console.log('La media es', media);

const numerosMayores = numeros.filter(numero => numero > media);

console.log('Números por encima de la media:',
    numerosMayores.toString(),'(', numerosMayores.length, ')');
```

Un par de consejos:

- Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript) sobre el uso de var/let/const.
- Usa nombres de variables descriptivos, hace que leer el código sea mucho más sencillo. El único nombre de variable de una letra generalmente aceptado es usar `i`/`j`/`k` para contadores en bucles.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! :)