# Error de variable no definida al generar un gráfico en NodeJS con Google chart

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código:
Básicamente es el código que ofrece Google en su documentación para utilizarlo junto con Node. Yo solo añadí una función autoejecutable asíncrona para poder lanzarlo y algún cambio más que comento bajo el código.

```javascript
(async () => {
    const GoogleChartsNode = require('google-charts-node');

    let datos = [
        ['Artículo', 'Stock'],
        ['308', 12637],
        ['GEN06', 8100],
        ['529', 7097],
        ['CONF1034', 4050],
        ['CONF6100', 1677]
    ];

    // Define your chart drawing function
    function drawChart() {
        const data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(datos);

        const options = {
            title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
            chartArea: { width: '50%' },
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Total Population',
                minValue: 0
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'City'
            }
        };

        const chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    // Render the chart to image
    const image = await GoogleChartsNode.render(drawChart, {
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
    });
    require('fs').writeFileSync('imagen.png', image);

})();
```

Al Extraer el array de datos del interior de la función drawChart y lanzar el programa, me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Page error: Error: ReferenceError: datos is not defined
> at drawChart (about:blank:12:56)
> at drawChartFn (about:blank:30:11)
> at about:blank:37:24

Soy incapaz de entender por qué razón me da este error ya que la variable datos sí que está definida y además está en un scope en el que sí es visible para la función drawChart.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: quien ejecuta _drawChart_ tu problema parece de alcance de variables te invito a leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/106042/28035

Comment: Te dice que no encuentra el array de datos, y dices que lo has extraído. ¿Podrías poner el código que realmente está fallando?

Comment: drawChart es lanzada por la función render del objeto GoogleChartsNode. Se ve claramente en el código. No es problema de scope. La variable datos es accesibe desde esa función ya que comparten el mismo scope.

Comment: Correcto, lo he extraído porque el código original le pasaba el array como literal directamente a la función, es decir:

const data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      [ 'Artículo', 'Stock' ],
      [ '308', 12637 ],
      [ 'GEN06', 8100 ],
      [ '529', 7097 ],
      [ 'CONF1034', 4050 ],
      [ 'CONF6100', 1677 ]
    ]);

Lo que hice fue extraer ese literal a una variable que está fuera de la función pero sí debería ser accesible en ella. Es entonces cuando devuelve el error descrito arriba.

Comment: Creo que ya se lo que está pasando, pero no sé solucionarlo. La función drawChart se pasa como argumento a la función render, la cual la llamará internamente como una especie de closure. Es posible que por esa razón drawChart no vea a la variable datos. ¿Cómo puedo acceder a datos desde drawChart teniendo en cuenta que a esta función se la llama desde otra función render?

Comment: Ya encontré la solución. El problema está en la función render y cómo trata internamente los parámetros que se le pasan. Para emplear datos externos a la función drawchart hay que pasarle al método render un string con la data. Os dejo la info por si alguien enloquece como me pasó a mí a sabiendas de que se estaba haciendo bien: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-charts-node