# Iteración del texto de una variable

Tags: javascript

Necesito iterar el texto de una variable (no el contenido). Coloco un ejemplo

```js
function abc() {
  var begin_1 = 20;
  var end_1 = 30;
  var begin_2 = 31;
  var end_2 = 53;
  var begin_3 = 48;
  var end_3 = 67;

  if ("a" == "a") {
    var change = true;
    var x = 1;
  }

  // Lo que debe ser
  //if (change) {
  //  document.getElementById("fini01").value = begin_1;
  //  document.getElementById("ffin01").value = end_1;
  //}

  // Lo que necesito
  if (change) {
    document.getElementById("fini01").value = begin_x; // En esta parte necestio que el valor de la variable begin_x tenga el valor begin_1, es decir, 20
    document.getElementById("ffin01").value = end_x; // En esta parte necestio que el valor de la variable end_x tenga el valor end_1, es decir, 20
  }
}
```

He tratado de hacerlo de las siguientes maneras, pero ninguna ha servido:

```js
document.getElementById("fini01").value = begin_+x;
document.getElementById("fini01").value = `begin_${x}`;
```

Como puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, antes que nada, tienes que definir las variables `change` y `x` ya sea fuera de la condición o como variables globales.

Volviendo al caso para iterar un texto con una variable puedas usar la función `eval()` de JavaScript que permite evaluar un string y devuelve el resultado como si fuera una sentencia.

```
function abc() {
    var begin_1 = 20;
    var end_1 = 30;
    var begin_2 = 31;
    var end_2 = 53;
    var begin_3 = 48;
    var end_3 = 67;

    let x
    let change = false

    if ("a" == "a") {
        change = true;
        x = 1;
    }

    if (change) {
        document.getElementById("fini01").value = eval(`begin_${x}`); 
        document.getElementById("ffin01").value = eval(`end_${x}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta era la solución que estaba necesitando. Emanuek, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Franceschi te invito a leer mas sobre el alcance de variables aqui =>https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/106042/28035

Comment: @JackNavaRow Agradezco la recomendación. Así lo haré.