# ¿Como puedo llamar a un div (en el que se encuentra mi formulario) con un boton y cada que funcione aparezca el div sin que afecte a los otros?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Estoy haciendo modificaciones en un proyecto, me pidieron que en un formulario que ya esta hecho agregar un botón a un apartado para que este agregue mas del mismo (se llama "Dependencias"), ahora hice una función en la cual clona el formulario (tengo un formulario principal y hice otro para el botón) pero no logro que funcione como lo necesito

1. el botón funciona agrega mas pero tengo que ocultar el formulario y esto hace que la información del primer apartado (que es el select que hace que se completen los demás) no aparezca
2. puse visible el formulario y ahora cada que presiono el botón y e seleccionado algo del principal este lo clona igual y si no selecciono nada en el principal la información no aparece
   [image: Mi vista con los errores que les comento]

Este es el código de mi formulario

```
<div id="formulariosuscribiente">
<div class="input-group">
                    <div class="col col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
                            <label for="title">Dependencia</label>
                      <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true"  name="suscribiente_id[]" id="selectD suscribiente_id" onchange="selectNit5(event)"  >
                      <option disabled selected value="">Seleccionar dependencia</option>
                            @foreach($suscribiente_gestor as $c)
                            <option data-nit3="{{ $c->nombre}}" data-nit="{{ $c->grado}}"  data-nit1="{{ $c->nombre_titular}}" data-nit2="{{ $c->cargo}}"value="{{$c->id}}">{{$c->nombre}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                       </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
                              <label for="title">Grado Académico</label>
                              <input    class="form-control"  readonly id="grado_suscribiente_convenio"   name="grado_suscribiente_convenio[]" required >

                            </div>
                       <div class="col col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
                              <label for="title">Titular</label>
                              <input    class="form-control" readonly  id="nombre_suscribiente_convenio"   name="nombre_suscribiente_convenio[]" required >
                          </div>
                              <div class="col col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
                                <label for="title">Cargo</label>
                                <input    class="form-control" readonly id="cargo_suscribiente_convenio"  name="cargo_suscribiente_convenio[]" required >
                                </div>
                                  <a class="remove-language remove-field">x</a> </div></div>
```

Este es el código de mi función en JS.

```
<script>
  function selectAgregarS(){
    //método clone Node en Javascript
    var p = document.querySelector(".input-group");
    var p_clonado = p.cloneNode(true);
    
    document.getElementById('formulariosuscribiente').appendChild(p_clonado);
     
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.input-group').parent().on('click', '.remove-field',function(){
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    });
  }
</script>
```

Este es otra función que usa para autocompletar los campos de enfrente (no tiene tanta relevancia pero para no confundirlos esta es la que llama onchange en el select)

```
<script>
  function selectNit5(e) {
    var nit =  e.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("data-nit")
      document.getElementById("grado_suscribiente_convenio").value = nit;
      var nit =  e.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("data-nit1")
      document.getElementById("nombre_suscribiente_convenio").value = nit;
      var nit =  e.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("data-nit2")
      document.getElementById("cargo_suscribiente_convenio").value = nit;
  }
  </script>
```

Soy nueva en JavaScript todo lo e estado buscando si algo no funciona como debería o esta mal planteado háganmelo saber con amabilidad, les agradecería muchísimo que me ayudaran llevo días dándole vueltas.

Si ustedes consideran otra opción para hacer la función díganmelo yo probé con cloneNode pero acepto sugerencias si hay algo mejor.

Comment: ¿Es la misma pregunta que tenías anteriormente?

Comment: ¿Dónde invocás a `selectAgregarS`? Además, creería que deberías prestar atención a `var p = document.querySelector(".input-group");`: ¿es siempre el primer elemento con clase _input-group_ el que querés clonar? ¿Por qué no tener elementos "genéricos" y crear los nuevos elementos en base a esos elementos? Digamos que los elementos "genéricos" son como "plantillas" que vas a clonar.

Comment: Nota al margen: [var, let, const... o nada en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/106042)

Comment: a selectAgregarS lo invoco en el boton del formulario principal con Onclick, disculpa no entiendo como podria hacer el elemento generico, si es siempre el mismo elemento que quiero clonar

Y si es una pregunta derivada de una anterior.

Comment: A lo que voy es que vía JS (o jQuery, ya que lo estás utilizando) crees los campos "base" (en vez de tenerlos en el HTML), y que esos elementos (que previamente llamé "genéricos") sean los que clones para agregar una nueva fila.

Comment: a ver segun entiendo eso lo hago con innerHTML en mi función ¿cierto?

Comment: No necesariamente. Por dar un ejemplo: en JS puro existe [createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) (¡ejemplos hay miles!). Para jQuery existen miles de otros ejemplos. Buscá además como agregar esos elementos al DOM.

Comment: Ok bien, voy a buscar ejemplos para aprender a realizarlo, usted cree que haciendo los elementos genericos pueda funcionar o hay algun otro error

Comment: Es cuestión de probar :)