# Quiero que dos select esten relacionados y el segundo dependa de la option que se eligio en el primero

Tags: javascript, html, objeto, javascript-metodo

Tengo este objeto y quiero que el select2 dependa de lo elegido en el select1.
Si elijo por ejemplo el departamento de Artigas
en el select1, el select2 deberia dejarme elegir las localidades de Artigas y Bella Union.

```
 var dptosLocs = {
 "Artigas":["Artigas","Bella Unión"],
 "Canelones":["Canelones","Santa Lucía"],
 "Montevideo":["Montevideo"],
 "Salto":["Salto","Daymán","Arapey"]
 };

 // Obtener llaves del arreglo
 var select1_val = Object.keys(dptosLocs);

// Obtener los valores de cada índice en un solo 
arreglo
var select2_val = Object.values(dptosLocs).flat();

var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
var select2 = document.getElementById("select2");

for(var i = 0; i < select1_val.length; i++) {
var opt = select1_val[i];
var el = document.createElement("option");
el.textContent = opt;
el.value = opt;
select1.appendChild(el);
}

for(var i = 0; i < select2_val.length; i++) {
var opt = select2_val[i];
var el = document.createElement("option");
el.textContent = opt;
el.value = opt;
select2.appendChild(el);
}
```

Cuando cambio en el select1 a otro departamento deberia cambiarme el select2 tambien con sus respectivas localidades. Que uno dependa del otro

```
//HTML

<form id="formulario">
 <select id="select1"></select>
 <select id="select2"></select>
</form>
```

Al seleccionar uno de los cuatro departamentos en el select el select2 deberia cambiar y mostrar sus localidades respectivas

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cargar un SELECT dependiendo de otro SELECT - Javascript - DOM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71985/cargar-un-select-dependiendo-de-otro-select-javascript-dom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre usando el evento 'change' que sirve para cuando un input cambia de selección y aprovechar ese momento para ir al 2do select, eliminando lo que tenía anteriormente y usando [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) para llenarlo con los nuevos valores:

```js
var dptosLocs = {
  "Artigas":["Artigas","Bella Unión"],
  "Canelones":["Canelones","Santa Lucía"],
  "Montevideo":["Montevideo"],
  "Salto":["Salto","Daymán","Arapey"]
};

let select1 = document.getElementById('select1')
let select2 = document.getElementById('select2')

Object.keys(dptosLocs).forEach(name => select1.innerHTML += `<option>${name}</option>`)

select1.addEventListener("change",(e) => {
  Object.entries(dptosLocs).forEach((elem) => {  // entries devuelve los pares clave valor en forma de array bidimensional
    if(elem[0] === e.target.value){
      select2.innerHTML = '';
      elem[1].forEach( elem => select2.innerHTML += `<option>${elem}</option>`)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
  <form id="formulario"> 
    <select id="select1">
      <option id="default">Seleccione Departamento</option>
    </select>
    <select id="select2"></select>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes lograr esto con un evento [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) que básicamente se activa cada vez que el elemento seleccionado cambie.

```js
var dptosLocs = {
  "Artigas": ["Artigas", "Bella Unión"],
  "Canelones": ["Canelones", "Santa Lucía"],
  "Montevideo": ["Montevideo"],
  "Salto": ["Salto", "Daymán", "Arapey"]
};

// Obtener llaves del arreglo
var select1_val = Object.keys(dptosLocs);

// Obtener los valores de cada índice en un solo arreglo
var select2_val = Object.values(dptosLocs).flat();

var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
var select2 = document.getElementById("select2");

for (var i = 0; i < select1_val.length; i++) {
  var opt = select1_val[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select1.appendChild(el);
}

for (var i = 0; i < select2_val.length; i++) {
  var opt = select2_val[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select2.appendChild(el);
}

select1.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var selectedDpto = this.value;
  var localidades = dptosLocs[selectedDpto];
  select2.innerHTML = ""; // limpia el contenido actual del select2
  for (var i = 0; i < localidades.length; i++) {
    var opt = localidades[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select2.appendChild(el);
  }
});

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  select1.value = "Artigas";
  select1.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
});
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
  <select id="select1"></select>
  <select id="select2"></select>
</form>
```